# Prevent HttpURLConnection from sending cookie

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have the following code:

```
URL uri = new URL(my_service_url);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) uri.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setRequestProperty("content-type", "application/x-www-form-url-encoded");
connection.connect();

// I process request here
```

It works ok most of the time, it is just **sometimes** the request has some headers I don't set, specifically some cookies like: "Cookie: JSESSIONID=XXXX". In my case this causes problems and my request sometimes fails because of this.

How can I make sure my request do not sent other cookies I don't set explicitly?

Comment: This cookie is set by the whatever it is that is serving your requests. Have you tried adding it to subsequent requests?

Comment: Sorry I could not understand very well. What do you mean by "Have you tried adding it to subsequent requests?"

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid sending cookies by explicitly setting it empty

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie","");
```